# Is it possible to target both iphone & ipad using the same project?

Tags: iphone, ipad, xamarin.ios

The subject is self explanatory, I have a current iPhone project using Monotouch/MonoDevelop and I want to be able to target iPad too.

Is there any way that the application could do a "stretch"? I have not tested the app in an ipad, only in the emulator and it does not look good.

Thank,
Ignacio

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. You can either programmatically check if app is running on ipad or on iphone and set different nib files for each mode.

Also you may use the same views either created programmatically or through Interface Builder, but in that case you should set your resizing masks properly.

Comment: If you create a project which targets both iPad/iPhone, MonoDevelop will auto-generate an separate App Delegate for each device, in here you can display the appropriate XIB files as you'd expect. So the checking is done for you